# How to extend this idea about virus spread?

Tags: types, ocaml

First, I have defined type:

```
type people_group = {
  people : char list; 
  distances : (char * float * char) list
};;
```

So this project is about virus spread. For example:

```
let group1 : people_group = {
  people=['1'; '2'; '3'; '4'; '5'];
  distances=[
    ('1', 0.3, '2'); ('2', 0.7, '1');
    ('1', 10.1, '3'); ('3', 3., '4');
    ('3', 0.1, '5'); ('4', 7., '5'); 
    ('2', 6., '3')
  ]
};;
```

In the above example, we have a group of five people (denoted by numbers). An element `('1', 0.3, '2')` from distances represent the distance (0.3 in this case) between 1st and 2nd man. If the distance (float) is > 0.5 then 2nd man got infection.

So I've made a function `quick_infection`:

```
let quick_infection (group : people_group) c =
  let first = function
    | (a, _, _) -> a
  in
  let scnd = function
    | (_, a, _) -> a
  in
  let third = function
    | (_, _, a) -> a
  in
  [c] @ 
  List.map 
    (fun x -> third x) 
    (List.filter 
       (fun x -> first x = c && scnd x > 0.5) 
       group.distances);;
```

which has two parameters (group of people and an infected man) and as an output gives a char list of people infected by a certain man + man who started spread, but after one step. Examples:

```
# quick_infection group1 '1';;
- : char list = ['1'; '3']
# quick_infection group1 '2';;
- : char list = ['2'; '1'; '3']
# quick_infection group1 ’5’;;
- : char list = ['5']
```

Now I want to extend this idea and make a function `chain_infection` which as an output gives a char list of people who got an infection indirectly. The example should best show how it works:

```
# chain_infection group1 '1';;
- : char list = ['1'; '3'; '4'; '5']
```

I feel that my previous function can help a lot, but I'm not sure how to use it. So any suggestions?

Comment: While not a solution to the larger problem, please note that you can save yourself a lot of trouble in writing `first`, `scnd`, and `third` functions and just use pattern matching more directly in your code. Instead of `fun x -> third x` you could simply write: `fun (_, _, x) -> x`. Instead of `fun x-> first x = c && scnd x> 0.5`, `fun (f, s, _) -> f = c && x > 0.5`.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to model an iterative process you should use recursion. The overall approach to your problem is that you start with the zero patient `c0` and get a list of people who are the first circle of the zero patient, `[c01,.., c0N] = quick_infection group1 '1'`. Now you go through each `c01`, till `c0N` an call `quick_infection` on it. You will get a list of lists, which you can flatten with `List.flatten`. Now you have the cohort of infected people, which you as well should map with `quick_infection` and then flatten. This process looks infinite and in fact it is, unless we add some more rules to our infection model. For example, we may add rules that the same person couldn't be infected twice, so that when we see a person that is already infected, we do not add it to the infected list. Now we can specify the termination criteria for the infection - it stops when the list of infected people stops growing.

Speaking OCaml, the general iterative procedure that uses recursion looks like this (where `<code-in-brackets>` corresponds to the user code that you shall fill in),

```
let rec loop input output = 
 if <check-condition> input output 
 then loop (<do-the-work> input output) 
 else output
```

This roughly corresponds to the imperative-style loop (in some C-style pseudo-language),

```
while (<check-condition>(input, output)) {
  <do-the-work>(input, output);  
}
```

Sometimes there is no output, or input is not changing in during the loop, or you need to add an [induction variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_variable) to the loop, e.g.,

```
let strnlen chars maxlen = 
  let rec loop i = 
   if chars.[i] <> '\x00' && i < maxlen 
   then loop (i+1)
   else i in
  loop 0
```

This example function, imitates the [strnlen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html) function that returns the number of characters before the `'0'` symbol or `maxlen`, whichever is smaller. This example also demonstrates a common approach to hide the loop as a helper function nested in the main function. Compare this to the C implementation of the same function,

```
int strlen(const char *chars, int maxlen) {
  int i = 0;
  while (i < maxlen && chars[i] != '\x00') {
     i++;
  }
  return i;
}
```

It is also worthwhile to know that your problem is easily modeled with [graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph), and in fact, your group is a graph. And the spread of virus is an instance of the [graph reachability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability) problem and you're looking for the transitive closure of the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of the relation `distance p1 p2 < 0.5`<sup>1)</sup>.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Your post and code say `> 0.5` but I believe it is a typo unless you're modeling an antisocial distancing infection that spreads only on the far targets and doesn't transition between people who are not maintaining the social distance :)

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking about this. But I don't know how to write the criteria: while the list is growing continue the process.

Comment: I added some examples of recursive functions, which I hope will help you to solve your task. Specifically for didactic purposes I do not include the solution. To figure out if list is growing you can compare the list before a call to `quick_infection` and after it with `List.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first off make this a bit more efficient by using maps and sets, rather than association lists.

```
module CharMap = Map.Make (Char)
module CharSet = Set.Make (Char)
```

Now we can take your record type and convert the association list to a map based on the "name" character.

```
type people_group = {
  people : char list; 
  distances : (char * float * char) list
}

let group1 : people_group = {
  people=['1'; '2'; '3'; '4'; '5'];
  distances=[
    ('1', 0.3, '2'); ('2', 0.7, '1');
    ('1', 10.1, '3'); ('3', 3., '4');
    ('3', 0.1, '5'); ('4', 7., '5'); 
    ('2', 6., '3')
  ]
}

let map =
  List.fold_left 
    (fun m (a, b, c) -> 
       CharMap.update
         a
         (function 
          | None -> Some [(b, c)]
          | Some lst -> Some ((b, c) :: lst))
         m)
    CharMap.empty
    group1.distances
```

Now, for flexibility, we can pass a function called "threshold" to determine whether transmission has occurred. To model your "> 0.5" rule, we'd use: `fun f -> f > 0.5`. Or perhaps: `Fun.flip (>) 0.5`.

The basic process will take a starting node `pat_z` for "patient zero," a threshold function, a map of nodes we call `group`, an accumulator of infected nodes, a set of nodes that have been visited and should not be considered further, and a set of nodes left to be processed.

When we consider a patient zero, we check first to see if it's been visited. If it has, then we don't consider any of its neighbors. If it hasn't, we filter out its infected neighbours.

The `to_process` argument serves as a stack of nodes to check which we either consume or populate. When there are no infected neighbors and no nodes left to process, the recursion is complete.

By processing through this way we achieve tail recursion, which along with the use of maps and sets (backed by balanced binary trees) lets the algorithm scale to large data sets. It also provides a way of managing the `visited` set on each iteration so that we don't get cyclic recursion.

```
let rec get_infected 
    (pat_z : char) 
    (threshold : float -> bool)
    (group : ((float * char) list) CharMap.t) 
    ?(acc : char list = [])
    ?(visited : CharSet.t = CharSet.empty) 
    ?(to_process : char list = [])
    () =
  let pat_z_visited = CharSet.mem pat_z visited in
  let infected_neighbors = 
    if pat_z_visited then []
    else
      match CharMap.find_opt pat_z group with
      | None -> []
      | Some lst -> 
        lst 
        |> List.filter_map 
             (fun (f, c) -> 
                if threshold f then Some c 
                else None)
  in
  match to_process with 
  | [] when pat_z_visited -> List.rev acc
  | x::xs when pat_z_visited -> 
    get_infected x threshold group ~acc ~visited ~to_process: xs ()
  | [] when infected_neighbors = [] -> List.rev @@ pat_z :: acc
  | x::xs when infected_neighbors = [] -> 
    get_infected x threshold group 
      ~acc: (pat_z :: acc) 
      ~visited: (CharSet.add pat_z visited) 
      ~to_process: xs 
      ()
  | _ -> 
    get_infected (List.hd infected_neighbors) threshold group 
      ~acc: (pat_z :: acc) 
      ~visited: (CharSet.add pat_z visited)
      ~to_process: (to_process @ List.tl infected_neighbors)
      ()
```

For you sample data, calling `get_infected '1' (Fun.flip (>) 0.5) map ()` looks something like:

```
get_infected '1' (Fun.flip (>) 0.5) map ()
get_infected '1' f map ~acc: [] ~visited: | | ~to_process: [] ()
get_infected '3' f map ~acc: ['1'] ~visited: |'1'| ~to_process: [] ()
get_infected '4' f map ~acc: ['3'; '1'] ~visited: |'1'; '3'| ~to_process: [] ()
get_infected '5' f map ~acc: ['4'; '3'; '1'] ~visited: |'1'; '3'; '4'| ~to_process: [] ()
['1'; '3'; '4'; '5']
```